# How do you get the local timezone offset in "+hh:mm" format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know how to get the current utc_offset using `Time.current.utc_offset` but how can I get it in the format "+hh:mm"?

The best solution I have so far is `DateTime.now.to_s[-6,6]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strftime` with `%z` (`:` means hour and minute offset from UTC with a colon):

```
Time.current.strftime("%:z")
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `formatted_offset`:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('America/New_York').formatted_offset
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-formatted_offset

Answer (score 0):

use this it will give current time local timezone offset in “+hh:mm” format.

```
Time.now.getlocal.strftime("%:z")
```